# Analog for TagView in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to have UI like this: 
[image]
With native Android it can be done with libraries like https://github.com/whilu/AndroidTagView, how can it be done with flutter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can make the same UI by combining the `Wrap` and `Chip` widget as @wasyl montioned . but this is a full example about what you need

**Notes :**

- you can adjust the space between the chips inside the Wrap widget
  using `spacing`
- the `deleteIcon` is only in the right but you can use the `avatar` to show an icon in the left
- you can set the `Chip` Border Color and width using the `Shape` property

[image]

```
 new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              Chip(
                label: new Text("Java"),
                onDeleted: () {},
                labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                deleteIcon: Icon(Icons.clear),
              ),
              Chip(
                label: new Text("C++"),
                onDeleted: () {},
                labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                deleteIcon: Icon(Icons.clear),
              ),
              Chip(
                label: new Text("Python"),
                onDeleted: () {},
                labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                deleteIcon: Icon(Icons.clear),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          new SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          new Wrap(
            spacing: 5.0,
            children: <Widget>[
              Chip(
                label: new Text("China"),
                backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
              ),
              Chip(
                label: new Text("USA"),
                backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
              ),
              Chip(
                label: new Text("Austria"),
                backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          new SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          new Wrap(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            spacing: 5.0,
            children: <Widget>[
              Chip(
                  label: new Text("نجربة"),
                  avatar: Icon(Icons.clear),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  shape: new BeveledRectangleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey))),
              Chip(
                  label: new Text("كتابة"),
                  avatar: Icon(Icons.clear),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  shape: new BeveledRectangleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey))),
              Chip(
                  label: new Text("مختلفة"),
                  avatar: Icon(Icons.clear),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  shape: new BeveledRectangleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey))),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Perfect, this is preciosly I looked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use:

- a [Wrap widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) to have your chips (tags) be positioned one by one, overflowing to the next row
- a [Chip widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Chip-class.html) for a material-design chip with text, optional delete button, delete callback etc.

Seems like the border width can't be easily set for a Chip, though, but the overall functionality is readily available

Comment: Perfect, this is preciosly I looked. Thank you.